# Docker container can't see a serial port device

Tags: bash, docker, serial-port, usb, device

I'm trying to run a Docker container with access to a serial port on the host.

Here is what I did:

- I used a Mac
- Installed drivers on the host
  (http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=229&pcid=41)
- Plugged in the device
- Ran `ls /dev/t*` that returned
  `/dev/tty.usbserial` - so it worked
- Ran the container, `docker run -it --privileged -v /dev:/dev
  node:4.4.0 /bin/bash`, and then `ls /dev/t*` inside the container which didn't return the `/dev/tty.usbserial` device...

I played a lot with different variations of parameters, but I haven't found the working one :)

Also the `--device` flag is not suitable for me since the device might be reconnected and the name could differ from `/dev/tty.usbserial`.

Comment: You said you're running on a Mac? Does this mean you're using docker-machine or something? If so the issue is probably to do with the device not being seen by the virtual machine where the docker containers run

Comment: I'm using the official docker toolbox (https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox). Then run `Docker Quickstart Terminal` and at this step I do see the device, just after I run a new container I don't see the device within the one.

Comment: If you run `docker-machine ssh <machinename>` can you the see the device in `/dev`? The Docker Quickstart Terminal just opens a terminal for you with all of the environment variables setup to talk to the docker daemon in the VM. See this link: https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ssh/

Comment: @sprkysnrky I run `docker-machine ssh default` and then listed the `/dev`, no device found...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by [*@pgayvallet* on GitHub](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3110#issuecomment-456853036):

> As the daemon runs inside a VM in Docker Desktop, **it is not possible to actually share a mac host device with the container inside the VM**, and this will most definitely never be possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the script described in *"[Notification of new USB devices in docker container](https://www.guidodiepen.nl/2016/05/notification-of-new-usb-devices-in-docker-container/)"* (from [Guido Diepen -- `gdiepen`](https://github.com/gdiepen)) can help.

He too runs his container with the `--privileged` argument to allow it to access the devices. And he mounts the host directory `/dev/bus/usb` to the `/dev/bus/usb` directory within the container with the argument `-v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb` when starting said container.

The script uses both `inotifywait` and `lsusb` to wait for devices to be (un)plugged and check if it was the device we are interested in.

> The `inotifywait` will keep on listening to inodes create/delete events under the `dev/bus/usb` directory and will execute commands whenever an `inode` corresponding to a relevant device has been just created.

See also, once you have detected an plugged USB device, *[How to get Bus and Device relationship for a `/dev/ttyUSB`](https://askubuntu.com/q/184526/5470)* (not related to Docker, but still relevant).

Comment: Thanks! Need to try that.

Comment: I discussed with the author of the post you pointed above. The solution shouldn't work because the device isn't visible when running `docker-machine`.

Comment: The link for *"How to get Bus and Device relationship for a /dev/ttyUSB"* (last paragraph) is (effective) missing - is `http://`.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thank you. I have restored the missing link.