# How to get flask-serial working in docker container?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, docker-compose, pyserial

I've created a webapp with Python and Flask where some data received via UART is displayed. The script is running on a Raspberry Pi Zero.

For the serial connection I use the [flask-serial](https://github.com/RedFalsh/flask-serial) module, which works pretty well. But now I converted the project into a docker image to handle SSL certificates with nginx, and gunicorn is used to pre-interpret the Python script so that it's faster.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it so that incoming serial messages are forwarded to the Python script and flask-serial?

My python script looks like this:

```py
import os
from   flask_migrate import Migrate
from   flask_minify  import Minify
from   sys import exit
from   apps import create_app, db
from   flask_serial import Serial

app = create_app(app_config)
Migrate(app, db)
ser = Serial(app)

# handle uart messages
@ser.on_message()
def handle_message(msg):
    # the magic happens here ...
```

The file apps/**init.py** looks like this:

```py
from flask import Flask

def create_app(config):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # configuration for flask_serial plugin
    app.config['SERIAL_TIMEOUT'] = 0.2
    app.config['SERIAL_PORT'] = '/dev/ttyS0'
    app.config['SERIAL_BAUDRATE'] = 115200
    app.config['SERIAL_BYTESIZE'] = 8
    app.config['SERIAL_PARITY'] = 'N'
    app.config['SERIAL_STOPBITS'] = 1

    register_extensions(app)
    register_blueprints(app)
    configure_database(app)

    return app
```

The docker-compose.yaml file looks like this:

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
  mywebapp:
    container_name: mywebapp
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    build: .
    networks:
      - db_network
      - web_network
    volumes:
      - /dev:/dev
    privileged: true
    tty: true
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    image: "nginx:latest"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./certs:/etc/ssl/certs
    networks:
      - web_network
    depends_on: 
      - mywebapp
networks:
  db_network:
    driver: bridge
  web_network:
    driver: bridge
```

The DOCKERFILE looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.9
# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY requirements.txt .
# install python dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
# gunicorn
CMD ["gunicorn", "--config", "gunicorn-cfg.py", "run:app"]
```

And I start the docker image with the following command:

```bash
docker-compose up --build
```

I already tried to fix it like it's shown in the tutorial on https://www.brewblox.com/dev/tutorials/serialscript but there it's made with the pyserial module instead of the flask-serial module and the pyserial module doesn't work how it should in a flask project.

Comment: Please expand on "fix it". What's not happening that you expect to happen. What's happening that you don't expect?  I have an educated guess that you're not binding gunicorn to 0.0.0.0, but without more detail, that's only a guess.

Comment: I bound unicorn to 0.0.0.0. The webserver itself is working great.
The problem is that the python script and flask-serial has no access to the uart messages of the serial interface.

I think it has something to do with how flask-serial works. It polls if a new uart message has received and if there is a message the function handle_message is called.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213812/docker-container-cant-see-a-serial-port-device might have bad news, if you're on a Mac